# Swift: addGestureRecognizer not work in class

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, unrecognized-selector

My class:

```
class SelectBox {
    internal static func openSelector(list:[String: String], parent:UIView){
        print("iosLog HELLO")
        parent.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleClick(sender:))))
    }

    @objc func handleClick(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("iosLog CLICK")
    }
}
```

Set view :

```
SelectBox.openSelector(list: AppDelegate.stateList, parent: bgPlaceInto)
```

After launch print `HELLO`, but after click on `view` i get below error :

> 2018-07-07 18:39:12.298322+0430 Ma[971:260558] [ChatService]: SMT:
>    2018-07-07 18:39:12.470392+0430
>   Ma[971:260525] [ChatService]: RCV:      2018-07-07 18:39:12.471851+0430
>   Ma[971:260591] [ChatService]: RCV: 
>   2018-07-07 18:39:14.674675+0430 Ma[971:260392] *** NSForwarding:
>   warning: object 0x100a9fc70 of class 'Ma.SelectBox' does not implement
>   methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead Unrecognized selector
>   +[Ma.SelectBox handleClickWithSender:] 2018-07-07 18:39:14.675210+0430 Ma[971:260392] Unrecognized selector +[Ma.SelectBox
>   handleClickWithSender:]

How i can set click listener to view by class?

Thank you

Comment: did you used 'isUserInteractionEnabled = true'

Comment: Try marking `SelectBox` as `@objc`?

Comment: You need to make `handleClick` static since `self` in `openSelector` is the class, not an instance of the class.

Comment: @V_rohit where ?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, but not work

Comment: @V_rohit That has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you, can you help me more?

Comment: @ComputerIm No since I have no idea what further help you need.

Comment: @ComputerIm Ah! I just realised you are doing this in a static method. **Don't**. Make it an instance method, create an instance of `SelectBox` and call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `openSelector` method is static. The word `self` in a static context, refers to an instance of the surrounding type's meta type. In this case, `SelectorBox.Type`.

Obviously, `SelectorBox.Type` does not have a `handleClick` method. `SelectorBox` does.

You need to make the `openSelector` method non-static:

```
internal func openSelector(list:[String: String], parent:UIView){
    print("iosLog HELLO")
    parent.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleClick(sender:))))
}
```

Now `self` refers to the `SelectorBox` instance.

You can call it like this:

```
// declare this at class level:
let box = SelectorBox()

// call the method like this
box.openSelector()
```

EDIT: Your class should look like this:

```
class ViewControllerPage: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource { 
    @IBOutlet var bgGenderInto: UIView!
    let box = SelectBox()  
    override func viewDidLoad() { 
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        box.openSelector(list: AppDelegate.genderList, parent: bgGenderInto) 
    }
}
```

Comment: @ComputerIm can you describe what happened? Any error messages?

Comment: only i get `iosLog HELLO` error, click on `parent` but not work

Comment: @ComputerIm did you remember to put the `box` at class level? I.e. outside of any methods

Comment: My class: `class SelectBox {
    internal func openSelector(list:[String: String], parent:UIView){
        print("iosLog HELLO")
        parent.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleClick(sender:))))
    }
    
    @objc func handleClick(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("iosLog CLICK")
    }
}` my code : `let box = SelectBox()
        box.openSelector(list: AppDelegate.genderList, parent: bgGenderInto)`

Comment: @ComputerIm where is this “my code” located at? In a method, right? That won’t work, you need  to move the `box` outside of the method.

Comment: Yes i use `box.openSelector(...)` in another class

Comment: @ComputerIm it doesn’t matter whether it’s in another class. The declaration of `box` has to be outside of any method.

Comment: Sorry, i cant understand. this is my full code : `class ViewControllerPage: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var bgGenderInto: UIView! override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() let box = SelectBox()
        box.openSelector(list: AppDelegate.genderList, parent: bgGenderInto)
        }`

Comment: Thank you. work fine. can you help me for this question? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51258784/swift-addgesturerecognizer-for-uiview-class

Comment: @ComputerIm it seems like the problem has been solved in that question. You should post another question regarding the problem with tags.

Comment: Thank you. i want add to 30 buttons and use `foreach`. how i can ?

Comment: @ComputerIm comments should not be used  as a place to ask new questions, you should post another question by clicking the “Ask Question” button.

Comment: Ok thank you. i create new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51265494/swift-scrollview-after-use-subviews-not-work