# Swift: addGestureRecognizer for UIView class

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I use this code:

```
class StarClass: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var bgStar: UIView!

    class func createMyClassView() -> StarClass {
        let myClassNib = UINib(nibName: "Star", bundle: nil)

        let nW = myClassNib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! StarClass
        nW.bgStar.layer.cornerRadius = 15

        nW.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleStar(sender:))))

        return nW
    }

    @objc func handleStar(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("iosLog STAR")
    }
}
```

After run, if I clicked on the view, I get error below:

> 2018-07-10 11:11:50.496349+0430 Ma[23098:89853] +[Ma.StarClass
>   handleStarWithSender:]: unrecognized selector sent to class
>   0x10ef5cac0 2018-07-10 11:11:50.513392+0430 Ma[23098:89853] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[Ma.StarClass
>   handleStarWithSender:]: unrecognized selector sent to class
>   0x10ef5cac0'
>   *** First throw call stack:...

Comment: It *looks* correct. You might try to split that line up into two separate lines: 1) `let tap = UITap...` and 2) `nW.add...(tap)`. I found it sometimes doesn't work properly when doing that in one line.

Comment: it sounds like the action is not correctly attached to the xib. Go to the xib, open left tab, go to most-left button (that's where you see all links to swift files). Delete the action one. Re-link.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. It seems to be not a code issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the line :

```
nW.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleStar(sender:))))
```

Here, inside a `class` function, `self` refers to the Class type, not its object. But you are adding the gesture recogniser on an object. The solution here would be to do this:

```
nW.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: nW, action: #selector(handleStar(sender:))))
```

Comment: thank you. i have another question. i set tag to parent view, but in function not return tag. `let view = StarClass.createMyClassView()
            view.tag = index`. `@objc func handleStar(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("iosLog STAR \(sender.view?.superview?.tag)")
    }` return null !

Comment: Because, you seem to be setting the tag of the view, but trying to retrieve the tag of its parent?

Comment: Yes i want get parent tag. how i can ?

Comment: view.superview.tag = x?

Comment: thank you. i set value into tag `sender.view?.superview?.tag = (sender.view?.tag)!`. but return 0 from out of class