# Swift: scrollview after use subviews not work

Tags: swift, scrollview

I want add sub view to the `scrollview` programmatically

If i add `subviews` to `scrollview`, scrolling not work

```
for subview in view.scrollView.subviews {
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
}

var j = 0
for value in getList {
    let viewChild = SelectClass.createMyClassView()
    viewChild.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    viewAll[j] = viewChild

    viewChild.title.text = value.value

    view.scrollView.addSubview(viewChild)

    j = j+1
}

var i = 0
for subview in view.scrollView.subviews {
    let item = subview as? UIView
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            (item?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.scrollView.leftAnchor))!,
            (item?.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.scrollView.rightAnchor))!,
             (item?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50))!
         ])

     if(i > 0){
         NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
             (item?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (viewAll[i-1]?.bottomAnchor)!))!
         ])
     } else {
         NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
             (item?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.scrollView.topAnchor))!
         ])
     }

     i = i+1
}

view.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
```

I try one view in `scrollView` but not work again

In normal storyboard work fine, but by `addSubView` not work

How i can fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it's better using `UIStackView` , here you need to add bottom constraint for the last item

```
if let last =  viewAll.last {
     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
         last.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.scrollView.bottomAnchor)
     ])
}
```

Comment: How will a `UIStackView` provide the scrolling behaviour that is required?

Comment: if you embed the stackView inside the scrollView it's easily to add subviews with **addArrangedSubview** without constraints , only set it's distribution to **fillEqually** and set the *stackViewHeight  = numberOfItems*itemHeight**

Comment: I see, yes that would make sense then you just need to setup the auto layout for the `UIStackView`.  Of course doing it with a `UIStackView` does rule out having self sizing sub views however.  Also without it it would be better to constrain the views to something outside the `UIScrollView` rather than the left and right anchors of the scroll view itself.

Comment: Thank you. if i use one view in scrollview, `last.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.viewIntoScroll.bottomAnchor)` not work for it. i mean `bottom space to container`

Comment: If your scroll view is fixed in height using auto layout constraints and you try to pin views to it that are in total less height (e.g. a single view) then that will cause a conflict in the constraints which will have to break one of them and it's probably that bottom anchor.  For example if you scroll view has a fixed height of 500 and you add two views each of which is 50 in height you can't pin them to the bottom as 50+50 doesn't equal 50 so something has to give.